# Limit of how many text messages can be sent with in app texting

Tags: ios, sms

I've built an app that uses in app texting. This app sends quite a bit of texts as part of its functionality. On some days, the texts do NOT go through - especially when connected with wiFi. When disconnecting the WiFi - everything works fine.

I'm wondering if this strange behavior is because the app has NOT yet been reviewed on the App Store? It's currently distributed via Test Flight. Even when the SMS's fail to go through - I am still receiving a "MessageComposeResultSent" in my 
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult) result

Answer (score 0):

The limit (per sprint networking team) is set a a control system that monitors each account.  Once the "limit" is reached, you can send anymore. That's it. I found a personal workaround, which is to use MMS, however that uses people's data plan.

Ultimately, sprint would not tell me the limit numbers, even though all phone numbers are in my contacts list.